# While loops with certain array conditions

Tags: python, numpy

Need some help with python code and some arrays:

Example

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
1   1   6
1   2   65
1   3   23
2.3 2   43
2.3 4   23
3.1 4   45
3.1 6   35
3.1 7   15
5   3   67
5   9   45
```

E.G. 3 columns of data and an arbitrary amount of rows

What I want to do is some operation for each column for all identical first entries of the column.

So for the above example: the script looks and sees that there are 3 rows with where the first column is 1 -- it then does some operation on these 3 rows -- lets say take the difference between the third column and second column. It then stores these values in an array -- so right now this array would have values:

store_values = [5, 63, 20]

It then searches for the next identical values in the first column: it sees that there are two 2.3. It then does the same operation (take the difference between columns 3 and 2) and appends the store_value array, so now:

store_values = [5, 63, 20, 41, 19]

It then searches again: sees two 3.1 -- does the same thing above, and it continues to do this, until it runs through all identical values. The txt is sorted -- as I think that would be easier to work with.

The final store_values = [ 5, 63, 20, 41, 19, 41, 29, 8, 64, 36]

Now I used a very basic example with the differences, as I know I can get the above array with just taking the differences and not worrying about the first column -- but my script is doing something more complex where it has to rely on the first column -- for example plotting column 3 and 2 for the identical first entries, doing a linear fit, and storing the slope in the array.

so far:

```
import numpy as np

data_file_name = 'whatever.dat'

data=np.loadtxt(data_file_name)
```

Hope this makes sense - if I need to clarify something, please comment

Comment: I should mention I have 25,000 rows of data -- so memory is an issue.

Comment: You don't really have a memory issue. 25,000 rows by 3 columns by 8 bytes for each float is 600kB. Your machine has 1,000-10,000 times as much memory as is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both `unique` and `where` from numpy to solve your problem. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np

data_file_name = 'in.txt'

data=np.loadtxt(data_file_name)

unique = np.unique(data[:,0])
out = []
for i in unique:
    ind = np.where(data[:,0]==i)
    out.append(data[ind,2]-data[ind,1])
outarray = np.hstack(out)[0]

print(outarray)
```

, the result is:

```
[  5.  63.  20.  41.  19.  41.  29.   8.  64.  36.]
```

Using `unique` function you don't need to have the elements sorted out. There are several other ways of solving this problem depending on other criteria you might have (for instance using lists uses more memory than needed), but this solution is clear and functional if your data is not too excessive.

Comment: YA I should mention I have 25,000 rows of data -- so memory is an issue. I will try this method and see how long it takes

Comment: @renegade memory expenditure is one thing, performance (speed) is another. Although possible, generally speaking having both is difficult since to have more speed you need to access faster which you do by putting stuff in ram. In any case 25000 lines is not much and the solution should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to do that, which is more versatile than numpy for grouping.

1. Read the data in DataFrame,

with read_table:

```
In [5]: df=read_table('so.txt',header=None,sep='\s+')    
"""
     0  1   2
0  1.0  1   6
1  1.0  2  65
2  1.0  3  23
3  2.3  2  43
4  2.3  4  23
5  3.1  4  45
6  3.1  6  35
7  3.1  7  15
8  5.0  3  67
9  5.0  9  45
"""
```

2. group data by column 0,

and organize columns  1 and 2 in arrays.

```
In [6]: groups=df.groupby(0)[[1,2]].apply(array)
"""
0
1.0     [[1, 6], [2, 65], [3, 23]]
2.3             [[2, 43], [4, 23]]
3.1    [[4, 45], [6, 35], [7, 15]]
5.0             [[3, 67], [9, 45]]

"""
```

3. use then as you want .

Plotting for example:

```
In [7]: for label,points in groups.iteritems(): plot(*points.T,label=label);legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is trivial, you might be overthinking the solution. I will answer based on my understanding of what you asked.

1. You can read in each line 1 at a time: `currentline = next(data)`
2. split at the spaces: `info = currentline.split()`
3. manipulate the values however you want

NB - the 'info' variable stores the data as a list. In your case, for line #1 `info = ['1', '1', '6']`

Hope this helps!